# Delete last 5 characters from HTML content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, string

I have this code (assume unable to modify)

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="content">2026-01-31-08:00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="content">2025-03-34-06:00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="content">N/A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="content">N/A</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "2026-01-31-08:00" are supposed to be dates, "N/A" should stay the same. I'm trying to format the dates by cutting off the extras with `.slice`, and format it to say "01/2026" and "03/2025" while the "N/A" stay the same.

I tried to use `:contains` to select the ones with number then format it but with no luck. Any ideas how to do so?

Comment: Did you get the date code from `new Date()`? Could you explain with more code?

Comment: Rather than say _"I tried..."_, include your attempts in your question. This makes helping you solve the problems with your code much easier

Comment: The title and description doesn't seem to match the result you want (ie _"month/year"_). Could you please [edit] your question to clarify? Also, don't forget to include those attempts you made

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to filter the elements by matching their content to a regular expression. Then replace the contents of those elements with the new text

```js
const dateMatcher = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}/;

$(".content")
  .filter((_, { textContent }) => dateMatcher.test(textContent))
  .text((_, date) => {
    const [, year, month] = date.match(dateMatcher);
    return `${month}/${year}`;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="content">2026-01-31-08:00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="content">2025-03-34-06:00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="content">N/A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="content">N/A</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

It's 2022 and [you might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```js
const dateMatcher = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}/;

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".content"))
  .filter(({ textContent }) => dateMatcher.test(textContent))
  .forEach((el) => {
    const [, year, month] = el.textContent.match(dateMatcher);
    el.textContent = `${month}/${year}`;
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :contains('-') to search for the hyphen.

```js
$(".content:contains('-')").each(function(){
  let date = $(this).html().split("-");
  
  $(this).html(date[1] + "/" + date[0]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="content">2026-01-31-08:00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="content">2025-03-34-06:00</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="content">N/A</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
        <span class="content">N/A</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the `date.pop()`?

Comment: @Juan sorry, I was asking the answer author. It just doesn't seem necessary

Comment: @Phil you are correct, I don’t actually need it now that I look at it. I was following the OPs notes

Comment: @imvain2 yeah, the question title doesn't seem to match what OP wants at all